# How to find the index of an arraylist in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of ArrayLists of T, and I am trying to find the index of the ArrayList that contains a certain object

```
private int indexOfItem(T item)
{
    int index = 10000;

    for(int i = 0; i < bigList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(bigList.get(i).contains(item))
        {
            index = i;
        }

    }
    return index;
}
```

this works but is there a better way to do this using the indexOf() method that arrayLists have?

Comment: you can do `return i;` in your if clause

Comment: Why do you return 10000 by default? Why not some impossible value like -1 instead? indexOf() would return the index of a list that is equal to item, and that is obviously not possible. because a list of items is never equal to an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what [`indexOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) does with one exception: As soon as you find the item, you can stop looking:

```
private int indexOfItem(T item) {
  for(int i = 0; i < bigList.size(); i++) {
    if(bigList.get(i).contains(item)) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```